# In magento 2 URLkey saving issue using programatically

Tags: magento2, url-key

We are using Magento 2.2.5.we have all store views and default store views are available. Like image http://prntscr.com/nnu4qd
some product are don't have the URL Keys in admin side.
we tried to save the product by manually Url key is generated for only All store views but its not for default store view.
we are writing a program to load product id and save the product again, in this case, url key assigns for default store view but not for all store views.
I need both all store views and default store views url key for the product.
how can I solve this issue?